# How to call an external function in node js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a little confused on how this works...

I am writing a node/express app and there is a function I just wrote in its own file, I need to use it in my route and I just want to call that function.

In the other file (tranformTheData.js) there is:

```
module.exports = {
    tranformTheData:function (data){
    console.log('whatever')
}
```

In my node app.js file I have

```
var formatJSON = require('./js').tranformTheData;
```

Can I just now use

```
formatJSON(data)
```

and utilitze this function? Or do I have to do something else, I have seen a few examples of doing this however they do not make sense to me.

Comment: that should work but your module.exports  is missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
// transformData.js
module.exports = {
    formatJSON: function(data) {
        console.log('whatever')
    },
    otherFunction: function() {

    }
}

// app.js
var tranformTheData = require('./path/to/tranformTheData.js');
var formatJSON = tranformTheData.formatJSON;
var otherFunction = tranformTheData.otherFunction;

formatJSON(data); // this will work
```

`module.exports` in this case is exporting an object literal, and the object has two functions. Requiring that file and assigning it to a variable will assign that variable to the object literal, which then has access to its methods.

When you call those methods, you can then pass in whatever params you want. In the case of `formatJSON`, it's accepting the `data` param.

Comment: Does the object literal have to have 2 functions? I really just need the one. Im assuming not but I figured I would ask. I get the idea though that you can add multiple functions and require only one module.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I was just emphasizing the correct structure of an object, and showing how you could require the module and access its functions. You can have as many or as little functions as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the missing closing bracket in transformTheData.js:

```
module.exports = {
    tranformTheData: function(data) {
        console.log('whatever');
    }
};
```

---

Now you should be able to `require` the file using its filename and call the function as you are trying to do:

```
var formatJSON = require('./transformTheData').tranformTheData;

formatJSON(data);
```